# how to get website content after fully loaded

Tags: php, parsing

I am trying to parse Website and change content inside.

```
$contents = file_get_contents('https://www.cex.io');
$contents = str_replace(
    array('Sign In', 'Create Account'),
    array('TEST1', 'TEST2'),
    $contents
);
echo $contents;
```

But it is not work . I think reason why not works is that website content loads after some seconds using JS.

How can I change content of such kind of websites?

Comment: You aren't going to get there with a simple parser like this, unless you have 100% control of the site that you are accessing. Instead, you need something that can parse and render HTML/CSS/JS/etc. and create a DOM, basically a browser. Take a look at [Symfony's Panther](https://github.com/symfony/panther).

Comment: You can try PhantomJS or CasperJS.

Comment: did you succeed John Doe. Did Symphonys Panther or CasperJS help you. Would be great if you inform us. Thx alot